Unsure why the beahviour of intval is diferent between PHP 7 and 8
I'm trying to understand why the behaviour of the intval PHP function varies between PHP 7 and 8.
For example, in a test script like...
<?php 
echo "test on " . phpversion() . " \n";
$test_var = "home";
echo "test_var is: " . $test_var . " \n";
if ( $test_var == intval($test_var) ) {
    echo "same \n";
} else {
    echo "not same \n";
}
echo "intval of test_var is: " . intval($test_var) . " \n";

...I think it should always be "not same", but it isn't in PHP 7.
So in PHP 7, the script outputs...
test on 7.4.33 
test_var is: home 
same 
intval of test_var is: 0 

And in PHP 8, the script outputs...
test on 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 
test_var is: home 
not same 
intval of test_var is: 0 

Can anyone please explain why PHP7 behaves this way?
The docs at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php don't explain.

It is not the function, it is the comparison operators that changed, https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/string_to_number_comparison explains the changes

On the page of https://wiki.php.net/rfc/string_to_number_comparison
you can read the line of
0 == "foo"   | true   | false


Furthermore:

Comparisons between strings and numbers using == and other non-strict comparison operators currently work by casting the string to a number, and subsequently performing a comparison on integers or floats. This results in many surprising comparison results, the most notable of which is that 0 == "foobar" returns true

So, in short, your string is converted into a number for the purpose of comparison and since it's not a number, it converts to 0, which is the exact result as that of intval($test_var)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

@NigelRen thanks for the comment. Is it a problem in this case that we have an illustration as well besides the relevant part of the text being shown and quoted? People with weak eyesight will not lose anything from the content, but it looks nicer for us. I certainly had no intent to discriminate anyone.
